# How would I make a web image viewer with a static image?

Tags: android

I am interested in making an application that does various things, but I am having trouble getting a static image, such as an avatar off of a web page.

Any ideas?

Comment: if it's a static image, why not just download offline it and include it in your app's resource bundle?

Comment: because the site im getting it from changes the picture but keeps the url the same. So everyday it should be a new image

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Visit this site:
[Here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-load-image-from-url-example/)